# VectorDrawable: Move the entire vector a few dp down

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

For example, I have `ic_chat_black_24dp.xml` vector asset from Android Studio,

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M20,2L4,2c-1.1,0 -1.99,0.9 -1.99,2L2,22l4,-4h14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2L22,4c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2zM6,9h12v2L6,11L6,9zM14,14L6,14v-2h8v2zM18,8L6,8L6,6h12v2z"/>
```

What I want is to have the start point `M20,7` i.e. start the image 5dp down; all lines, everything. I can change the `ViewportHeight` to 29.0 to enhance the canvass but how do I use it?

Do I have to change each `Y axis` value individually or there's a faster way?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can move the entire path by wrapping it in a `<group>` tag, which would look something like:

```
<group
    android:translateY="5">

    <path
        ...your stuff.../>

</group>
```

The group also allows you to change 'scale' and 'rotation' properties as listed in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html).